# Couldn't get id of dynamically created checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have check boxes dynamically created, on each clone i increment the id of the checkbox and put the same name to the class of the div on which i want to perform action after checking that checkbox.
Now the problem is that when checkbox is cloned with new id on clicking that new box the alert doesn't work even though i have same class on both old and new check boxes.
I haven't pasted the clone js code but it's working correct all fields are getting cloned with new id's and classes.
Here is the snippet for checkbox html and JS.

```js
var chauffeur_index = $('.check_chauffer').length - 1;
$('.check_chauffer').last().attr('id', 'Chauffeur_details_' + chauffeur_index);
$('.Chauffeur_details').last().addClass('Chauffeur_details_' + chauffeur_index);

$(function() {
  $(".check_chauffer").change(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.' + this.id).removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
      $('.' + this.id).addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="check_chauffer" id="Chauffeur_details_0" name="check_chauffer">Chauffeur
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<input type="checkbox" class="check_airport" name="check_airport" id="airport_details_0">Airport
<span class="help-block"></span>

<div class="Chauffeur_details_0 hidden">
  <div class="col-md-2 booking_details">
    <h6><strong>Booking Details:</strong></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="">Per Hour Rate</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" name="Chauffeur_per_hour_rate[]" class="form-control " required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="">Min Hours/Day</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" name="Chauffeur_min_hours_booking[]" class="form-control " required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <label for="">Max Hours/Day</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" name="Chauffeur_max_hour_perday[]" class="form-control" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if anyother code is required please ask me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: use,
`$( document ).on( 'click', '.check_chauffer', function() {
   alert( 'your code' );
});`

Comment: tried that already, but it's not working

Comment: You should probably be using a version of jQuery that's a little bit newer than `1.9.1`. That was probably released 10 years ago.

Comment: ohh that version could be the problem @DrewKennedy ?

Comment: I don't think that version is even compatible with Bootstrap, which it looks like you're using.

Comment: `$(".check_chauffer").live("click", function(){
   alert();
});`, this is for old versions

Comment: the above comment is if your `jquery` version is below `1.7`

Comment: @DrewKennedy - on event is coming from 1.7.2 version onwards the Op using 1.9.1 version that is not an issue

Comment: @Sravan it says `add_chauffeurrates:1560 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function`

Comment: sorry, you are using Jquery `1.9.1`, `live` will not work for you.

Comment: @DrewKennedy it turned out that i'm using 1.11 version of jquery, but i have included 1.9 in the snippet

Comment: @HabibRehman - live is deprecated using on event is good in your context because you using 1.9.1

Comment: @Habib, re-check if your cloned checkbox has the same class,

Comment: yes my cloned checkbox has same class. Every cloned checkbox has same class but different id's

Comment: also make sure that method is getting called, put it in `document.ready`, or once try the same in browser console.

Comment: hurray it worked now @Sravan

Comment: @Habib, good, added as an answer, please check now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is, you should add a `delegate` to the event handler.

**The `.on()` method allows you to delegate any desired event handler to: current elements, or any future elements which might be added to the DOM in a later time.**

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.check_chauffer', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

The second thing is to make sure you add it in `document.ready`.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.check_chauffer', function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

[Reference of direct-and-delegated-events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: thanks for skimming the problem with me :) (and someone gave -1 idk why)

Comment: :)  glad to help you, I don't know who gave that.

Comment: You probably got a -1 (not me) as the problem has been asked 20 times *today* (possible exageration) for which a simple search would find the issue,

Answer (score 1):

Use **Event Delegation** for dynamically created attributes and elements in the dom elements.It allows us to attach a single event listener for elements that exist now or in the future. Inside the Event Handling Function.

```
$(document).on('change', ".check_chauffer", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```